# Flask static folder not working on pages that take parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

My static files seems to work on all my pages except when a page takes a parameter. Here is my code:

**folder structure:**

```
[WEB]
    myApp.py
    [templates]
        test.html
    [static]
        [img]
            my_image.png
```

**Flask app:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
from Cheetah.Template import Template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'THIS_WILL_BE_SOME_RANDOM_KEY'
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def main_route():
    return redirect('/home')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return str(Template(file="templates/test.html"))

@app.route('/somePage')
@app.route('/somePage/<var>/')
def somePage(var=None):
    return str(Template(file="templates/test.html"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

**test.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><img src="static/img/my_image.png"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so basically the **home** page and the **somePage** page should both display the same image and normally it does, however when i pass an argument to **somePage/var** it fails to find the static folder, it instead looks for /somePage/var/static and it gets the 404 error bellow

```
"GET /somePage/var/static/img/my_image.png HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Did i do something wrong? 
is my static folder not set up the right way? 
why does it work on **/home** and **/somePage** but not **/somePage/var** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative URL to load static elements. This won't work for *any* URL with a path with more than one slash in it.

Use the `url_for()` function to generate an absolute path instead:

```
<div><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/my_image.png') }}"></div>
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me right away because my real problem was that I was using Cheetah templates instead of jinja templates. My site was originally powered by cherrypy which i often use alongside cheetah and when i made the switch to flask to try it out i neglected to also switch template engines. Anyways your answer helped me figure out my error and you were fundamentally right regarding my use of relative paths so thank you.